# how to stay on window/tab without actually stay on that tab

Tags: javascript, html

i watch video on website, when i change to other tab
video is stop playing. and when i change to old tab, video is playing

i want to know there is a trick to prevent video from stop playing?
already try scrollIntoView, focus but not working at all

this is my code (not working)

```
var requiredElement = document.querySelector('.watch-area-inner');
requiredElement.focus();
requiredElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check for `blur` and `focus` events on `window`.
Read the [Page Visibility Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to understand how it works. But, I guess there is no way to fake it.